# jQuery plugins for a sliding menu (like mmenu)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, menu

I was wondering if anybody knew of a plugin that allows you to create a sliding menu that looks like a native (kind of) menu for iphone/android and that is compatible with jQuery.

I tried mmenu (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl) but it kind of lags when I integrate it to my website, and I would like to explore other alternatives.

Also, do you know if I can create this with Bootstrap (I have never tried bootstrap though)?

Thank you in advance for your support and recommendations!

Answer (score 1):

This links will help you.

http://www.programming-free.com/2013/02/responsive-navigation-menu-using.html

and

http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: If this answer helped you to solve your problem you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

here is the custom code for the menu you show in link.

CSS code

```
.deviceMenu {background:green; width:150px; height:250px; -webkit-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out; -moz-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out; -ms-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out; -o-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out; transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;}
    .btnMenu { width:70px; height:50px; background:yellow;}
    .show{ margin-left:150px;}
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="deviceMenu">
   <div class="btnMenu">show/hide</div>
   </div>
```

jQuery to show/hide menu

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.btnMenu').on('click', function(){
        var $$ = $(this),
            $menu = $$.parent();
        ( !$menu.is('.show')) ? $menu.addClass('show') : $menu.removeClass('show');

    });

});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5R7H2/